# AWK convert minutes and seconds to only seconds

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file that I'm trying to convert into just seconds.  It looks like this:

```
49.80
1:03.40
1:01.00
1:00.40
1:01.00
```

I've tried:

```
awk -F: '{seconds=($1*60);seconds=seconds+$2;print seconds}' file
```

which outputs:

```
2988
63.4
61
60.4
61
```

I've also tried:

```
sed 's/^/:/g' file | awk -F: '{seconds=($2*60);seconds=seconds+$3;print seconds}'
```

Which outputs the same as results.  I would like to obtain these results:

```
49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a check for if the records contains both seconds and minutes

```
awk -F: 'NF==1; NF==2{seconds=($1*60);seconds=seconds+$2;print seconds}'
```

- `NF` number of fields in each record(row).
- `NF==1` If it contains only one field, we are not gonna do any calculations. See that there is no `{action}` part associated with this check. Hence `awk` performs the default action to print entire line
- `NF==2` True if the string contains 2 fields. Takes the associated action, which performs the calculations.

**Test**

```
$ awk -F: 'NF==1; NF==2{seconds=($1*60);seconds=seconds+$2;print seconds}' file
49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
```

Answer (score 1):

last column in your colon-separated list are seconds, next-to-last are minutes and the column before them are hours (although not mentioned before). This structure I'd put into code:

```
awk -F':' '{print (NF>2 ? $(NF-2)*3600 : 0) + (NF>1 ? $(NF-1)*60 : 0) + $(NF)}'
```

It checks whether there are enough columns (e.g. `NF>1`) and then takes its value (e.g. `$(NF-1)*60` or even `0`).

Test:

```
> awk -F':' '{print $0": "(NF>2?$(NF-2)*3600:0)+(NF>1?$(NF-1)*60:0)+$(NF)}' 
49.80: 49.8
1:03.40: 63.4
1:01.00: 61
1:00.40: 60.4
1:01.00: 61
23:14:12.1: 83652.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F: '{print (NF-1)*$1*60 + $NF}' file
49.8
63.4
61
60.4
61
```